# Autocomplete for namedtuples (python) for Pydev, Eclipse?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

As above, I'd love to have some autocompleting for namedtuples in python, is there anyway to do? I use Pydev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyDev doesn't currently analyze namedtuples to give you a better introspection for it. Please enter that as a feature request in the PyDev tracker (see: http://pydev.org/about.html for links).